# phpunit - No tests excuted and weird output

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.5

I'm using Laravel 5.5 for playing around with tests but somehow they are not working properly and it isn't outputting well in command-line.
It's a fresh Laravel app, so all I did was run `phpunit` in command line. Result:

[image]

I also did `php artisan make:test PageTest` and created a test case but still not getting anything. Besides, why isn't showing any color but instead these really weird symbols?

composer.json: `"phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"`

Already tried changing from `"phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"` to `"phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"` and running `composer update` but I got `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getTestdoxGroupConfiguration()`

phpunit.xml:

[image]

Comment: The "weird output" is for ANSI consoles, to display text in different colors. See https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/516

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `vendor/bin/phpunit` did not work for me. Simply changing to `vendor\bin\phpunit` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Try **vendor/bin/phpunit** instead of **phpunit** it might works.

Comment: I think your answer would be better if you explained it like this: "Instead of simply running `phpunit`, try the command `vendor/bin/phpunit`." I don't want to edit it myself, because that's a big change. But your answer is basically correct.